# Which Western democracy has the harshest punishments for corruption charges?

Tags: law, western-world, corruption

> Xu Guojun, the head of a Bank of China branch in Southern China from
> 1993 to 2001, was convicted of embezzling 2.3 billion yuan ($325m;
> £255m).
>
> The case is the latest development in President Xi Jinping's
> anti-corruption programme that is focussed on the country's $60tn
> financial industry.
>
> Many banking officials and executives have been caught up in the
> crackdown.
>
> According to statements from the court, Xu and two other former Bank
> of China employees took advantage of loopholes in the lender's fund
> management system to obtain false loans.

https://www.bbc.com/news/business-67724241

It's undeniable that China has the harshest sentencing for corruption charges as people get commonly slapped with life sentences or worse, but I was wondering which Western democracies have the harshest punishment for such crimes. I know that Western democracies tend to be more lenient towards people who commit fraud or corruption and they rarely if ever get life sentences.

Comment: Interestingly, perhaps, NZ has among the lowest corruption rates in the world. Corruption in ANY context is addressed vigorously and considered socially unacceptable by the very large majority of society, *but* the penalties for corruption are on a far lower level than for eg China or US.

Comment: One theory suggests that corruption is a method of control in China. Pretty much everyone participates in corruption and the punishments are used as threats to keep people in line and make examples of those that fall out of line. The people at the top cant reach the top without being corrupt or having some sort of leverage against them. Corruption offers a relatively easy method of incentives and control. Xi's anti-corruption campaign appears to be more designed on ousting rival faction members over actual rooting out of crime. This would partially explain the harsh consequences.

Answer (score 3):

Probably USA (depending on your definition of "Western")  The USA tends to have longer prison sentences than Europe.

Corruption is not a named crime in Europe, instead the crime might be "bribery" (and can be of public or private individuals)  In most of Europe it carries a sentence of up to 10 years (ie somewhat longer than the sentence for theft)  In the USA it carries a maximum sentence of 15 years.

Alternately the crime might be "Fraud", and this carries a higher penalty, in theory including a life sentence in the UK, but in practice less than that.  Mr Xu seems to have been guilty of fraudulent embezzlement rather than accepting bribes.

These are maximum sentences, and sentencing guidelines for judges will start with a shorter term and then consider mitigation and aggravation - such as whether the offence was repeated, and the harm done by the offence.  For example in the UK, the maximum sentence is 10 years. Still, an offender with high culpability and an offence of bribery that causes the most harm would have a "starting point" of 7 years imprisonment, and normally (when other factors were considered) a 5-8 years sentence.  The offender could expect parole after about 4 years.

However within this framework, the USA tends to give longer custodial sentences, and this includes (for example) the 13 year custodial sentence given to Congressman William J Jefferson in 2009 (even though it was later reduced)'

Comment: "Corruption is not a named crime" seems like stretch.  "Les affaires" was widely talked about in France in the 90s when I lived there.  Circumstances that were often not exactly fraud or bribery, terms that have narrower meanings.  cf.  Chirac's grocery bills while Paris mayor (illegal campaign funding, btw).  Whatever its name, and I don't how *you* decide what the word for "corruption" is called in Spanish, Finnish or Dutch, European countries have legislation against it just fine.

Comment: It depends on the definition of "corruption."  Nepotism, for example, is not considered to be a form of corruption in most circumstances.  And it's fairly common.

Comment: @Italian  What I mean is that, when charged, you are charged with a particular crime eg "Murder" or "theft". These are legal terms that can vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction, eg "larceny" is not the word used in England, but it is used in the USA. In the jurisdictions which I'm most familiar with, the crime on the charge sheet will be "bribery" or "fraud" or "theft", and not "corruption".  Of course, what you call it doesn't matter so much, but there are certain sentencing guidelines that are indexed by the name of the crime.  You can look up the sentencing guidelines for bribery.